# OPENCV OPENVINO cv2.rectangle

Tags: opencv, openvino

I am using opencv and openvino and am trying to figure out when I have a face detected, use the cv2.rectangle and have my coordinates sent but only on the first person bounded by the box so it can move the motors because when it sees multiple people it sends multiple coordinates and thus causing the servo and stepper motors to go crazy. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally, each code would run line by line. You'll need to create a proper function for each scenario so that the data could be handled and processed properly. In short, you'll need to implement [error handling](https://dzone.com/articles/error-handling-strategies) and data handling (probably more than these, depending on your software/hardware design). If you are trying to implement multiple threads of executions at the same time, it is better to use multithreading.

Besides, you are using 2 types of motors. Simply taking in all data is inefficient and prone to cause missing data. You'll need to be clear about what servo motor and stepper motor tasks are, the relations between coordinates, who will trigger what, if something fails or some sequence is missing then do task X, etc.

For example, the sequence of Data A should produce Result A but it is halted halfway because Data B went into the buffer and interfered with Result A and at the same time screwed Result B which was anticipated to happen. (This is what happened in your program)

It's good to review and design your whole process by creating a [coding flowchart](https://press.rebus.community/programmingfundamentals/chapter/flowcharts/) (a diagram that represents an algorithm). It will give you a clear idea of what should happen for each sequence of code. Then, design a proper handler for each situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more insights of your (pseudo-)code, please?

It sounds easy - you trigger a face-detection inference-request and you get a list/vector with all detected faces (the region-of-interest for each detected face) (including false-positive and false-positives, requiring some consistency-checks to filter those).

If you are interested in the first detected face only - then it could be to just process the first returned result from the list/vector.

However, you will see that sometimes the order of results might change, i.e. when 2 faces A and B were detected, in the next run it could still return faces, but B first and then A.
You could add object-tracking on top of face-detection to make sure you always process the same face.
(But even that could fail sometimes)

Comment: @kucci have you found useful answers to your questions, are you still working on a solution?